# Minecraft Spigot Config.yml color change not working

Tags: java, minecraft, spigot

I created a Timer for minecraft Spigot. In the Config.yml I added "&" coded for the color.
[But in Minecraft It looks like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aszFj.png)

My code looks like this:

```
prefix: '&6Timer &7»'

#%d% -> Tage
#%h% -> Stunden
#%m% -> Minuten
#%s% -> Sekunden
actionbar: '&7» &c&l%h%:%m%:%s%'

#Nachrichten
resume: '&aDer Timer wurde fortgesetzt'
pause: '&aDer Timer wurde pausiert'
reset: '&aDer Timer wurde zurückgesetzt'
running: '&cDer Timer läuft bereits'
not_running: '&cDer Timer läuft nicht'
paused: '&7&o» &6&oDer Timer ist pausiert'
over: '&cDie Zeit ist abgelaufen!'
remain_time: '&cEs sind noch &4%t% &cSekunden übrig'
reverse: '&aDer Timer läuft nun rückwärts'
unreverse: '&aDer Timer läuft nun vorwärts'
set: '&aDer Timer wurde auf &6%t% &agesetzt'
get: '&aZeit: &6%t%'
```

If you need anything else, just write me.
Thanks for your help

Comment: This does not look like Java code, please provide your full code?

Comment: Hi here ist the full code: https://github.com/Viiiinx/Timer

Comment: I fixed the error. I forgot to add `ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', getConfig().getString("pause"));`

Answer (score 2):

This is because `&` is only used in the .yml because the file cannot be written with `§`. You have to replace the `&` with `§`

Comment: Still don´t work

Comment: Ahh, I am sorry. It has to be `§`

Comment: & is used for Bukkit color codes.

Comment: Maybe because bukkit replaces them before sending the package, but looking directly in the minecraft source only `$` is used for color codes

Answer (score 1):

You have to translate the ColorCodes like this

```
String original = "&7&o» &6&oDer Timer ist pausiert"
String translated = ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', original);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use § instead of &.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).